# Parallel (2) 20 amp 220 12 ga wires into one 30 amp 220 Breaker OK?

Tags: circuit-breaker, oven, 240v

I am attempting to replace 2 ovens that currently each have their own dedicated 20 amp 220v circuits. (12 ga wire)

My new modern GE double oven requires a single 30 amp, 220 circuit. (10 ga wire)

Since they are dedicated wires going to the same place, and my new 30 amp 220 breaker accepts (2) 12 ga wires, can't I just wire these in parallel? Red to Red, Black to Black, White to White? Two 12 ga should theoretically be good up to 40 amps, and I am only going to ask for 30 amps tops.

I know it would be better to pull 50' of dedicated 10 ga cable but it would be very difficult with my home layout. Unless one of the paralleled 12 ga wires spontaneously broke by itself I can't see any danger such as the full load of 30 amp attempting to be carried by the single 12 ga wire?

Or,,,, should I stick with the 4 breakers I currently have, (each 20 amp), and just join them at the connection to the oven... That way each breaker is protecting a single 12ga wire and would trip if any one of them went individually over 20 amps. (it may sound strange but the current configuration has 4 separate 20 amp breakers,,, not 2 legs ganged/joined together.)

I hope that makes sense.. Thanks anyone for your help!!!

Herb

Comment: It makes sense only when dealing with normal currents, in the event of faults and fault current, it’ll burn your house down.  The wire needs to be replaced.

Comment: Thank you Tyson,, OK,, I think I understand why paralleling might be bad.. But what about just keeping my (4) 20 amp breakers and just joining the wires at the junction to the oven. Each wire is still protected at it's capacity, and at the oven I should have the 30 amp capacity I need? 2 reds. 2 blacks,2 whites?

Comment: No, that won’t work either.  Sorry but there is only one thing that works: change the wire.

Comment: Thanks again Tyson... I was hoping that this might work.. Even if it isn't truly per code,, I'm not sure how it could be a hazard if each independent leg is separately protected with it's own appropriately sized breaker.

Comment: Again, think about a worst case example. I know of someone that had a freak accident with a 4 wheeler in a garage that caused damaged to a wall with the oven and hot tub running through it.  If you have a LOOP like you suggest, you're going to burn your house down again!.  Code exists for a reason, it's the rules, it's the safe way.

Comment: When you say "4 breakers" do you actually mean two 2-pole breakers?

Comment: Thanks Tyson,, I'm obviously not a Licensed Electrician, but I can't understand any possible scenario could cause a single 12ga wire that is protected with a 20 amp breaker to exceed it's current draw, (and overheat/fire), without tripping the breaker. I do understand now how connecting both 12ga to a 30amp breaker in parallel "could" cause an unbalanced load if one 12ga wire was broken and the remaining 12ga wire was burdened with the full 30 amp load.

Comment: Hi Harper,, NO,, I actually mean 4 separate 20 amp breakers. To fully turn off power to each oven, I had to physically turn off 2 for the top oven, and 2 for the bottom oven. I suspect that probably isn't per code as well since if I turned off one breaker and not the other I was supplying the 240v oven with only 120v.

Comment: @herbg because two 12AWG wires feeding a combined 40A into a circuit, can pit 40A on a single neutral wire.  Neutrals are not fused.  The entire basis for architecting North American service the way we do, is that it's impossible for a neutral to carry more current than its partner hot (hots in MWBC).  The same applies to grounds, a 12AWG ground can't be counted on to ground 30-40A of bolted fault, hence the requirements for 10AWG grounds on 30-40A circuits.

Comment: Hi Harper,, Thanks and apologies for my ignorance. At the oven opening I have 2 sets of 4 wires. (one for each oven) They are red, black, white, and ground. If I join the reds and blacks I think I should have 240v with each leg of 12AWG protected by it's own 20A breaker.  The white 12AWG neutrals will also be joined at the oven which should give me enough capacity to carry the 30A max back. In addition, I have 2 grounds that I can connect together. Under this scenario, is my only risk that the unfused white neutrals are actually running in parallel?

Comment: You have several risks. One is of owning a mortgage on a burnt out house when insurance refuses to pay.  Another is when the buyer's inspector discovers the shoddy work, discovers all the work was unpermitted, and the AHJ makes you tear it out, pull permits and redo it.  I have seen this happen to neighbors.   You have but 3 options: get correct ovens, install correct wiring, or get two 10kva transformers to carry the needed power over a single 12/2. I recommend the first one, back to Home Depot it goes. An oven change alone, absent any wire work, doesn't need a permit. Wire changes do.

Comment: Thanks Harper,, no mortgage,, and the house will never be sold while I'm alive. The oven is great, and the same as all modern ovens... so you guys have convinced me to pull 10/3 through the attic and install the correct 30 amp breaker. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 3):

In a very simple answer NO. NEC forbids paralleling conductors less than 1/0. Article 310.10 (H)(1)

Comment: Thanks Retired Master Electrician...OK,, I think I understand why paralleling might be bad.. But what about just keeping my (4) 20 amp breakers and just joining the wires at the junction to the oven. Each wire is still protected at it's capacity, and at the oven I should have the 30 amp capacity I need? 2 reds. 2 blacks,2 whites? – or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: @HerbG how do you plan to protect the neutrals?  Neutrals are not breakered.

Comment: @Harper it is a 220V, no neutrals, he should be using double-pole circuit breakers

Comment: Ranges usually call for neutral.  They're used for the controls and the **oven light** since 240V bulbs are hard to source here.  Oven lights must be incandescent (or, I suppose, HID) because they must be OK with getting rather hot.

Comment: Hi Harper,, I guess the neutrals are the same as currently installed.. No breakers on them. Just a breaker on each leg of the 220V.  But I would expect the breakers to trip if either leg got overloaded. Still not sure why the approach to join the wires at the oven wouldn't work and be safe as well, even if not necessarily per code.

Comment: Thanks Dr Yunke,, I thought the current set up using (4) individual 20 amp breakers instead of (2) ganged 20 amp breakers was a little strange. (but I bought the house with it this way). If I swapped out the (4) 20 amps for (2) ganged (20) amps and then joined them at the junction to the oven (75' away), would that keep me from having to pull a new 10/3 wire and installing a single 30 amp ganged breaker?

Comment: As RME said there is no way to do this within code short of pulling new wires. trying to justify feeding 1 device with 2 sets of wires is creating a fire hazard and a hazard for someone later that turns off 1 set of breakers but not both. Code limits parallel wire sets to 1/0 or larger. Small gauge wire used in residential is easily damaged especially solid wire that most homes are wired with its not safe.new construction requires AFCI'S in many locations now for this very reason. Please don't try to justify code violations when several people have told you it is not safe and a code violation.

Comment: Appreciate your counsel Ed Beal.. I could live with the risk regarding turning off one set of breakers and not the other... but not if there is any additional risk of fire hazard. I'll guess I need to figure out how to run some new 10/3 wire.